# Script com ajax não entra na primeira condicional IF

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-4

Bom dia. Sou iniciante ainda na programação. Estou com problema em uma parte do código, onde após a mensagem de sucesso era para entrar na condicional IF. Como ele não entra no IF para adicionar a classe success do boostrap e limpar os campos, ele exibe a mensagem 'Senha alterada com sucesso!' mas adiciona a classe danger e não limpa os campos, e o código foi executado, por que no caso a senha é alterada normalmente no banco.

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#salvar').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                url: "alterar_senha.php",
                method: "post",
                data: $('form').serialize(),
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(mensagem) {
                    $('#mensagem').removeClass()

                    if (mensagem == 'Senha alterada com sucesso!') {
                        $('#mensagem').addClass('alert alert-success col-md-12 text-center')

                        $('#senha_antiga').val('')
                        $('#nova_senha').val('')
                        $('#confirma_senha').val('')
                        
                    } else {
                        $('#mensagem').addClass('alert alert-danger col-md-12 text-center')
                    }
                    $('#mensagem').text(mensagem)
                },

            })
        })
    })
</script>
```

Arquivo alterar_senha.php:

```
<?php

require_once('../conexao.php');

session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['nome_usuario']) || $_SESSION['funcao_usuario'] != 'Administrador') {
    header("location:../index.php");
}

// Recebe as informações do formulário
$senha_antiga = $_POST['senha_antiga'];
$nova_senha = $_POST['nova_senha'];
$confirma_senha = $_POST['confirma_senha'];
$senha_usuario = $_SESSION['senha_usuario'];
$id_usuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];


if ($senha_antiga == '') {
    echo 'Preencha o campo senha antiga!';
} elseif ($nova_senha == '') {
    echo 'Preencha o campo nova senha!';
} elseif ($confirma_senha == '') {
    echo 'Preencha o campo repita a nova senha!';
} else {

    // Verifica se as senhas digitadas correspondem
    if ($nova_senha != $confirma_senha) {
        echo 'As senhas digitadas não correspondem!';
    }

    $res_c = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE senha = '$senha_usuario'");
    $dados_c = $res_c->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $dados_senha = $dados_c[0]['senha'];


    if (!password_verify($senha_antiga, $dados_senha)) {
        echo 'A senha antiga não confere!';
    }

    //HASH DA NOVA SENHA
    $senha = password_hash($nova_senha, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    //ATUALIZAR A SENHA DO USUÁRIO NO BANCO DE DADOS
    $res = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE usuarios SET senha = :senha WHERE id = :id");
    $res->bindValue(":senha", $senha);
    $res->bindValue(":id", $id_usuario);
    $res->execute();

    echo 'Senha alterada com sucesso!';
}
```

Comment: Você pode usar o $.ajax com a função "done" após ela. Mais ou menos assim: $.ajax( ... códigos ... ).done(function(mensagem){ ... verificações ... }); Ao invés do "success" dentro do ajax. Aó você coloca um console.log(mensagem) Pra ver o que está vindo.

Answer (score -1):

Cara, parece que o problema pode estar na sua verificação de igualdade no `if` dentro da função `success` do Ajax. Certifique-se de que a mensagem retornada do PHP é exatamente `'Senha alterada com sucesso!'` (sem as aspas simples) e que não há nenhum espaço extra ou caractere especial. Uma maneira de depurar é adicionar um console.log na variável mensagem para ver o que é retornado.`

é bom tbm voce verificar se não há erros no console do navegador e se o jQuery está sendo carregado corretamente. e certifique-se de que os IDs dos campos de senha estão corretos e que eles correspondem aos IDs usados no jQuery.

umma sugestão é adicionar uma mensagem de erro genérica dentro do else do if dentro da função success, para garantir que a mensagem de erro seja exibida quando houver algum erro inesperado.

ve se esse exemplo te ajuda man, na func `success` um exmplo para tu depurar ela

```
    success: function(mensagem) {
  console.log(mensagem);
  $('#mensagem').removeClass();

  if (mensagem.trim() === 'Senha alterada com sucesso!') {
    $('#mensagem').addClass('alert alert-success col-md-12 text-center')

    $('#senha_antiga').val('')
    $('#nova_senha').val('')
    $('#confirma_senha').val('')

  } else {
    $('#mensagem').addClass('alert alert-danger col-md-12 text-center')
    $('#mensagem').text('Erro ao alterar senha!')
  }

  $('#mensagem').text(mensagem)
},
```

ve se te ajuda ai, fiz dando uma olhada por cima apenas, bons estudos.

Comment: Eu fiz conforme orientado, ele entra direto no erro ao alterar senha, porém a senha é alterada normalmente no banco de dados. Eu tenho o mesmo script em outro sistema e lá ele funciona normalmente.